# Dual Screen error "gdbus.error:org.gtk.gdbus.unmappedgerror.quark._gnome_2drr_2error_2dquark.code2"

Tags: 14.04, display

I am having trouble with my laptop when trying to extend my desktop. For a long time (a couple of months) I could extend it fine. However (either after installing CUDA for coursework, or after an update), it broken. The resolutions are correct for each display, but the second one always gets shifted to the right, and overflows to the other side. As well as this, it has become unusable due to lag (the mouse will not move for upwards of 15 seconds). Every time I try and set it up I get either *gdbus.error:org.gtk.gdbus.unmappedgerror.quark._gnome_2drr_2error_2dquark.code2* or *could not set the configuration for CRTC 64*.

I have noticed other graphical bugs as well, such as terminal lines/characters not appearing when they are actually there, and *gedit* not updating unless the whole window is moved to refresh it.

Specs:
Toshiba Satellite P850-12Z (Intel i7, NVidia 630M, 8GB RAM, 64GB Hard Drive space)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Nvidia binary drivers (v. 340.29)

When trying to take a screenshot, the displays are in the correct place.

Comment: Do you have the same problem as this one that includes a photo of the screen?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/557846/split-screen-problem-with-nivida-geforce-gtx-770m

Comment: Yes. If I swap round the monitor and the laptop screen on the screen display menu, the same thing happens on the other screen.