# Split screen problem with Nivida GeForce GTX 770M

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

### The Info

I am running a laptop with dual graphics cards: Intel and the Nvidia GrForce GTX 770M

I have the Nvidia drivers installed

I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64 installed

The second monitor shows in the system settings, and all of the settings are properly set

### The Problem

When I plug in my external monitor (via VGA) I get this weird split screen problem as depicted in the following picture:

[image: problem]

*Sorry for poor picture quality, my phone stinks for a camera*

When I go into the Nvidia control panel and switch to my Intel card the problem is gone but I need the power of my Nvidia card. Any ideas?

If you need more info feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. You have probably two graphic controllers one is *GeForce GTX770M* and second is integrated in processor *Intel GMA 4000*. Run *nvidia-settings* and check which one you have currently using. After changing from NVIDIA (Performance Mode) to Intel ( Power Saving Mode) my 2 screens started to working properly.

Comment: I did notice that and it did fix it, but I need the performance.